# ActiveRecord query with multiple joins not recognizing the relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to write an ActiveRecord Query that returns all students enrolled in a certain course with the following query:

```
def self.students_enrolled_in(course_id)
    Student
        .joins(:enrollments)
        .joins(:sections)
        .joins(:courses)
        .where(sections: { course_id: course_id })
  end
```

the result in the rails console is:

> ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Can't join 'Student' to association named 'sections'; perhaps you misspelled it?

it seems that the association is made. what am I doing wrong? does the query actually mean that all the `join()` statements have to relate back to Student, or should ac trace out the relational links?

Professor show page:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
  <h2 class="card-title"><%= @professor.name %></h2>

    <% @courses_taught.each do |course| %>
        <div class="card mb-4 card-header">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/750x300" alt="Card image cap">
          <h3 class="card-text"><%= course.title %></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <% course.sections.enrollments.students.each do |student| %>
              <p><% student.name %></p>
          <% end %>
        </div>
    <% end %>

</div>
```

models:

enrollment

```
class Enrollment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :section
  belongs_to :student
end
```

Student:

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :enrollments
end
```

Professor:

```
class Section < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :enrollments
  belongs_to :professor
  belongs_to :course

  validates_uniqueness_of :professor_id, scope: :course_id

  scope :by_professor_id, ->(prof_id) { where('professor_id = ?', prof_id) }
end
```

Course:

```
class Course < ApplicationRecord
  enum status: { planning: 0, offered: 1 }

  scope :offered, -> { where(status: 1) }
  scope :planning, -> { where(status: 0) }

  belongs_to :department
  has_many :sections
  has_many :professors, through: :sections

  validates :title, :number, :status, :description, presence: true
  validates :description, length: { in: 10..500 }
  validates :title, :number, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

  def self.search(term)
    if term
      where('title LIKE ?', "%#{term}%").order('title DESC')
    else
      order('title ASC')
    end
  end

  def self.taught_by(professor_id)
    Course
        .joins(:sections)
        .joins(:professors)
        .where(sections: { professor_id: professor_id })
        .select('distinct courses.*')
  end

end
```

Schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20171013201907) do

  create_table "courses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "description"
    t.string "number"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "status", default: 0
    t.integer "department_id"
    t.index ["department_id"], name: "index_courses_on_department_id"
  end

  create_table "departments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.text "description"
    t.text "main_image"
    t.text "thumb_image"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "enrollments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "section_id"
    t.integer "student_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["section_id"], name: "index_enrollments_on_section_id"
    t.index ["student_id"], name: "index_enrollments_on_student_id"
  end

  create_table "professors", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "status", default: 0
    t.integer "department_id"
    t.text "bio"
    t.index ["department_id"], name: "index_professors_on_department_id"
  end

  create_table "sections", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "number"
    t.integer "max_enrollment"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "professor_id"
    t.integer "course_id"
    t.string "room"
    t.index ["course_id"], name: "index_sections_on_course_id"
    t.index ["professor_id", "course_id"], name: "index_sections_on_professor_id_and_course_id", unique: true
    t.index ["professor_id"], name: "index_sections_on_professor_id"
  end

  create_table "students", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.decimal "gpa"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "name"
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "roles"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're over-applying `.joins`. Try starting from the inside out. First, find the course:

```
Course.find_by(id: course_id)
```

Then, find all the sections associated with the `course`. No need to do a `joins` here:

```
Section.where(course: Course.find_by(id: course_id))
```

Now you do your join:

```
Student.joins(:enrollments).where(enrollments: {section: Section.where(course: Course.find_by(id: course_id))})
```

I *think* that ought to do the trick for you. But, untested. So, give it a go and see if it works.

P.S.: Try posting only the most relevant code. It's not so much fun to sort through a bunch of extraneous stuff.

Comment: thank you, i will test it now. wasn't exactly sure what was relevant in this case, if knowing how the entities were related was pertinent or not, so they were included.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do this is to add some more associations to your `Student` model:

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :enrollments
  has_many :sections, through: :enrollments
  has_many :courses, through: :sections

  scope :enrolled_in_course, -> (course) { joins(:sections).where(course_id: course.id)
end
```

You can then find all students enrolled in a `course` with:

```
Student.enrolled_in_course(course)
```